# recommendation for web visualization dependency tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependencies, visualization

i have a database that lists a bunch of applications and their dependencies.  Some dependencies also have other dependencies.  I am trying to figure out a web based way to visualize this on a web page so you can see the whole list of recursive dependencies throughout the data. i am using asp.net mvc.  any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [QuickGraph](http://www.codeplex.com/quickgraph/) to model the dependency graph, then export it as [GraphViz](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visualization%20Using%20Graphviz&referringTitle=Documentation) or [GLEE](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visualization%20Using%20Glee&referringTitle=Documentation), then render it to PNG and show that image on your webpage.

Comment: i would like it to be interactive (user can click on links if possible) so saving as an image is not ideal but thanks for the option

Comment: you could build an image map (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp) to make nodes clickable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some JavaScript library for that.
One example of such is [Draw2d](http://draw2d.org/draw2d/).

Answer (score 1):

We have been using a directed graph library from [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.htm) for a couple of years and are really pleased with it. They have libraries for all kinds of developer technology.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to list all the apps with two sublists for each: "depends on" and "is dependency for". Then may be allow to expand "depends on" list by resolving all the possible dependencies.

The hardest is a map. May be there's a library for making them. Though I doubt it will be useful for a user to traverse along the connections in such a map, when he want's to find out if two applications depend on each other. Yet it'd be the ultimate goal if you want to demonstrate the big picture.